# Cant'see an item "local database" to add to a project in VS 2015 community

Tags: visual-studio-2015, localdb

Project -> Add -> New item. In that list of items I just see "Service-based database", it has ".mdf" when created. But I wanna add local database (.sdf).
It said in the book, which I use to learn C# )) maybe it's because book describes older version of VS? I'm confused...

I've installed SQL Data Tools with VS installer, also I downloaded and installed SQLLocalDB. But it doesn't help...
How can I create local database? Or this item doesn't exist anymore in newest versions of VS?

Comment: this is a picture of what I'm talking about
http://joxi.ru/823gKXYH68nZR2

Comment: can you try using SQL Server Explorer and adding a database from there.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: yes. It's because of version of VS. Microsoft refused to use .sdf from VS2013 , so I had to install VS 2012. In VS2012 I found what I seeked for )